# I want to open SSAS 2000 cab file

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssas, mdx, olap, bids

I have SSAS cube zip file schm.zip [for how to create](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312399)

I have only this cab file no database nothing.

this file has multiple files having extension dim_, dimcr_ , dimprop_ , dimtree_

I want to open this file using sql server 2005. which tools i may required to open this? i have ANALYSIS SERVICES (DEVELOPMENT WIZARD) installed only with sql server , Management studio.

any help will appreciated.

Aamir Khan
   JSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your cab to a MSOLAP2000 Server and then use the Migration tool in SSAS 2005.